# Issue with custom jQuery selectbox - keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery

I have issues with customized select box, i've done customization with this solution for example:
- http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/

I've tryed many others aswell... It's always same result. Issues remains, which is I can't type in a letter for example "T" for Texas, but instead scroll all the way down in order to select Texas.

Anyone perhaps familiar with this issue, is this a bug or is it just how it works?

I've checked all similair questions, but found no right answer or solution.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior expectedly because select HTML tag is substitute for many HTML span elements. The behavior presskey on select tag and item selected in list not implemented in this plugin.

You have possibility to implement extension of component for this specific case.